# Issue with deleting a Mac account through system preferences

Tags: snow-leopard, system-settings, accounts, macos

I have a desktop mac with multiple users and I would like to erase just one user from the computer but when I open system preferences and click on the accounts area, the minus sign to delete the account is grey and cannot be clicked. I checked all the other users on the computer and they are the same way. Everything is unlocked and I have the administrator password so I shouldn't have any problems but I am unable to click the delete key. Is there another way to delete a user account without damaging the computer or any other accounts?

Answer (score 4):

In order to add/delete accounts you have to unlock first:

[image]

which will prompt you for an Administrator account/password. Once entered successfully you can select and delete any user *not currently logged in*.

Comment: The OP mentioned that " everything is unlocked." Maybe the user in question is actually logged in?

Comment: I agree, that's why I've added the last part in italics. Let's wait for his/her feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You said you have an administrator password but you have to be signed in to an account that currently has administrator privileges. Only an administrator can delete accounts.

Make sure you are an administrator and the account you are trying to delete is NOT the one you are signed in with.